# i am not able display content of file using stream lit on to the web page

Tags: python, file, output, streamlit, file-not-found

```
import  streamlit as st

st.write('THis Streamlit')

st.success('Success')

with open('test.txt') as f:
    print(f.readline())
```

[output on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zT3y.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please provide a **[Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (min-reprex)**, and show us what you want, what you're currently getting, or your current error message, and what you've tried so far, also see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also see [**How to write a perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question)

Comment: Are you sure that the **"test.txt"** file is in the same path?

Comment: Aso, you are using `print` which prints in console. You need to use `st.text` or `st.write` to show the content in the app